# Managing collection of items through adding/removing

Tags: php, class, oop

I want have an in-memory data structure to be able to add or remove an item (in this instance a student) into some sort of table (just like a shopping cart) from the collection class I have created. At the moment, it just displays students. For instance, if I click add student, it will pop up below, and I can delete this student from below also.

How I could implement this?

Here is my Member.php class

```
<?php
 class Member {
  private $name;
  private $age;
  private $gender;
  private $course;

  public function __construct($name,$age, $gender, $course){
  $this->name = $name;
  $this->age = $age;
  $this->gender = $gender;
  $this->course = $course;
  }

  public function setName($name) { //Sets the age value

  $this->name = $name; 

  } 


 public function setAge($age) { //Sets the age value

 $this->age = $age; 

 } 



 public function setGender($gender) {  //Sets the gender value

 $this->gender = $gender; 

 } 

 public function setCourse ($course) {

    $this->course = $course;
 }

 public function getName() { //Gets the name value

 return $this->name; 

 } 

 public function getAge() {  //Gets the age value

 return $this->age; 

 } 


 public function getGender() { //Gets the gender value

 return $this->gender; 

 } 

 public function getCourse() {
     return $this->course;
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Here is my ObjectCollection.php

```
  <?php
 class ObjectCollection  
 {  
//This is an array to hold line items
  private $items_array ;

 private $itemCounter; //Count the number of items

 public function __construct() {
//Create an array object to hold line items
$this->items_array = array();
$this->itemCounter=0; 
 }

public function getItemCount(){
return $this->itemCounter;
}  

public function addItem($item) {
 $this->itemCounter++;
 $this->items_array[] = $item;
}

public function getItem($index) {
return $this->items_array[$index];
}
}
?>
```

And finally displaying this through testcollection.php

```
<?php
$ObjColl = new ObjectCollection();
$member1 = new Member("Jessica Davidson", 21, "Female", "Computing");
$ObjColl->addItem($member1);
$member2 = new Member("Lucy Barnes", 22, "Female", "History");
$ObjColl->addItem($member2);
$member3 = new Member("Mark Smith", 24, "Male", "Social Science");
$ObjColl->addItem($member3);

for($i = 0;$i < $ObjColl->getItemCount();$i++){
$item = $ObjColl->getItem($i);
if ($item instanceof Member) {
print "<br> University Member: ";
}

print "Name: " . $item->getName();
print ". Age: " . $item->getAge();
print ". Gender: " . $item->getGender();
print ". Enrolled on: " .$item->getCourse() . " course<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first if your ObjectCollection must collect only objects of Member class, use parameter type declaration. It’s good practice in OOP.

```
public function addItem(Member $item)
```

At second if you want work with ObjectCollection like with array, implement ArrayAccess and Iterator interfaces.

Example

```
<?php
class Member{
    private $__name;

    public function __construct($name){
        $this->__name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->__name;
    }
}

class MemberCollection implements ArrayAccess, Iterator{
    private $__Collection = [];

    private $__position = 0;

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->__Collection[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->__Collection[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->__Collection[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->__Collection[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->__Collection[$offset]) ? $this->__Collection[$offset] : null;
    }

    function rewind() {
        $this->__position = 0;
    }

    function current() {
        return $this->__Collection[$this->__position];
    }

    function key() {
        return $this->__position;
    }

    function next() {
        ++$this->__position;
    }

    function valid() {
        return isset($this->__Collection[$this->__position]);
    }

    public function addItem(Member $Member){
        $this->offsetSet(null, $Member);
    }
}

$MC = new MemberCollection();

$Member1 = new Member('Name 1');
$Member2 = new Member('Name 2');

$MC->addItem($Member1);
$MC->addItem($Member2);

foreach ($MC as $Member){
    echo '<br>' . $MC->key() . ':<br>';
    var_dump($Member->getName());
}

unset($MC[0]); //Delete member from collection
?>
```

Comment: Thats great help thank you @RomanAngelovskij. How could I implement this to allow the user to add and remove them from say a table if you know what I mean?